# How to get string when click on text in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list string like below.

```
<p>sub1/sub2/sub3</p>
```

How can we get sub1 if mouse clicks on sub1?
For example:

- If click on sub1 return `sub1`
- If click on sub2 return `sub1/sub2`
- If click on sub3 return `sub1/sub2/sub3`

How can I do that?

Comment: that impossible, Please use `<span>sub1</span>`

Comment: As you have a single text node within the `p` you cannot easily determine which word was clicked on. A better approach would be to put each word in its own element and then add click handlers to those elements.

Comment: encapsulate each in new `span` and check where the mouse is clicked and then decide.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap `sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3` into span ?

Comment: You can not do it , you have to use 2 different <p> tags for the same.

Comment: @ King Stone,@Allan Raquin,@Kaushik, All thing load from database, I can't put it in to a span

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All thing load from database, I can't put it in to a span

In this case split the text by `/` in to an array, then wrap each element in the array in a `span` and append it back to the DOM. Then you can add the delegated event handler to get the text of the current element and all previous siblings. Try this:

```js
$('p')
  .html((i, h) => h.split('/').map(w => `<span>${w}</span>`).join('/'))
  .on('click', 'span', function() {
    var text = $(this).prevAll().addBack().map((i,e) => e.textContent).get().join('/');
    console.log(text);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>sub1/sub2/sub3</p>
<p>sub4/sub5/sub6</p>
```

> On IE it does not work

This is because I used ES6 arrow functions, which IE doesn't support because it's incredibly outdated. If you need IE support change those to anonymous functions:

```js
$('p')
  .html(function(i, h) {
    return h.split('/').map(w => `<span>${w}</span>`).join('/');
  })
  .on('click', 'span', function() {
    var text = $(this).prevAll().addBack().map(function() {
      return this.textContent;
    }).get().join('/');
    console.log(text);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>sub1/sub2/sub3</p>
<p>sub4/sub5/sub6</p>
```

Comment: When he clicks on the second one, he want the first one too
"if click on sub2 return sub1/sub2"

Comment: Because I used ES6 arrow functions, which IE doesn't support because it's incredibly outdated. If you need IE support change those to anonymous functions. I updated the answer with an example of that

Answer (score 1):

One way you can surround each text with *span* element:

```js
$('p').html($('p').text().split('/').map(el => '<span>'+el+'</span>').join('/'));
$('span').click(function(i){
  var j = $(this).index();
  var t;
  if(j > 0){
    t = $('span:lt('+j+')').map(function(_,s){
      return $(s).text();
    }).get().join('/');
    t = t+'/'+$(this).text();
  }
  else t = $(this).text();
  console.log(t)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>sub1/sub2/sub3</p>
```

Comment: False, he said "if click on sub2 return sub1/sub2"

Comment: @Jérémy, you are right, didn't notice that. There might be other feasible solution, I have updated the answer with a solution:)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a markup like `<span data-sub="1">sub1</span>/<span data-sub="2">sub2</span>/<span data-sub="3">sub3</span>`, so you will know which part of the text was clicked.

```
$('[data-sub]').on('click', function (event) {
  const currentNumber = $(event.currentTarget).data('sub');
  let texts = [];
  $('[data-sub]').each(function (index, element) {
    if ($(event.currentTarget).data('sub') <= currentNumber) {
      texts.push($(element).text());
    }
  });
  return texts.join('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using only javascript with your main paragraph having an id of `subs`:

```js
const subs = document.querySelector('#subs');

subs.innerHTML = subs.textContent.split('/').map(function (text, i) {
    return `<span data-nr="${i + 1}">${text}</span>`;
}).join('/');

subs.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    const spans = Array.prototype.slice.call(subs.querySelectorAll('span'));
    const texts = spans.filter(function (span) {
        return span.dataset.nr <= evt.target.dataset.nr;
    })
    .map(function (span) { return span.textContent; }) ;

    console.log(texts.join('/'));
});
```